# Stacking many infinitives

Tags: passage-request, infinitive

Consider the sentence: *Dixit se velle posse audere venire*.
("He said that he wants to be able to dare to come.")
This has a stack of four infinitives.

In theory we might be able to stack as many infinitives as we like; maybe you can argue that just stacking arbitrarily many copies of *posse* and *velle* will make some logical sense.
Therefore I want to ground this more practically:
How many infinitives do we find stacked in extant Latin literature?

By a stack of infinitives I mean that they are nested.
In my example the object of *velle* is *posse audere venire*, that of *posse* is *audere venire*, and that of *audere* is *venire*.
An example of infinitives that are **not** stacked would be: *Dixit se et velle et posse venire*.
Here *velle* and *posse* are parallel to each other, not one governing the other, so there number of stacked infinitives is two.
The infinitives need not be next to each other.

I was unable to find more than two infinitives (like *posse fieri*).
Do we have three somewhere?
Or even more?

(This was inspired by [an earlier question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/18783/79) and Sebastian's answer to it.)

Comment: I would expect at least three to be possible. By the way, do you count a.c.i.?

Comment: @Cerberus Yeah, ACI is fine and maybe even the historical infinitive. It's hard to draw clear boundaries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tria infinitiva:

- *Sexto intervallo ab aequinoctio autumnali **incipere** scribunt **oportere serere** usque ad diem nonagensimum unum.* – Varro, [De re rustica 1, 34](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/L/Roman/Texts/Varro/de_Re_Rustica/1*.html#34).
- *… docuimus Deum necessario existere, hoc est, Deum non **posse desinere esse**, seu in alium Deum transformari …* – Benedictus de Spinoza, [*Cogitata metaphysica*, Pars II, Cap. IV. *De immutabilitate Dei*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Opera_philosophische_omnia_edidit_et_pr/MJwpAAAAYAAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&pg=PA65&printsec=frontcover).